# Extract all groups after character with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

The goal is to extract all the pairs *key/value* from a string which has the following format:

`(&(foo=bar)(goo=car))` or `(|(foo=bar)(goo=car)(hoo=dar))`

> I don't know how much groups are there, could be 2, could be 50.

I need to extract the operator (*& or |*) and the single params.

I tried the following regex, but it ignores the first group:

`([|&])((\(.*?=.*?\)))+`

How can I get all the groups?

[my attempt](https://regex101.com/r/vK4pN8/23)

**EDIT**

I think I might got it working by applying 2 regexps

`\(([|&])(.*)\)`

this will extract only the content

`(foo=bar)(goo=car)`

and this would extract the content

`\((.*?)\)`

`foo=bar, goo=car`

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/QYCupF/1 Or the content inside the groups? `\([|&]\(([^=()]*=[^=()]*)\)\(([^=()]*=[^=()]*)\)\)`  https://regex101.com/r/o2jYGQ/1

Comment: Yeah, but that stops working if I have a third group. I'll edit the question to make it clear that more than 2 groups can be in the string

Comment: You can not dynamically add groups 3, 4 etc.. you would have to add them. But the approach of 2 patterns could work.

Comment: I'm testing it now, I'll answer myself if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do everything as expected

```js
@Injectable()
export class QueryService {

regex1: RegExp = new RegExp("^\\(([|&])(.*)\\)");
regex2: RegExp = new RegExp("\\(([&|]\\(.*\\)\\(.*?\\)).*?\\)|\\(.*?\\)", "g");
regex3: RegExp = new RegExp("\\((.*?)\\)");

constructor(){}

decode(query: string): Query {
    if (!this.regex1.test(query)) {
      console.error("Error while parsing query", query);
      return;
    }
    const matches = query.match(this.regex1);
    const parts = {
      operator: matches[1] as QueryConditions,
      content: matches[2].match(this.regex2)
    };

    return new Query(parts.operator, this._getQueryFields(parts.content));
}

private _getQueryFields(content: string[]): GenericObject {
    const mapped: GenericObject = {};
    forEach(content, (g) => {
      if (this.regex1.test(g)) {
        mapped.group = this.decode(g);
      }
      else {
        //
        const pair = g.match(this.regex3)[1].split("=");
        mapped[pair[0]] = pair[1];
      }
    });

    return mapped;
  }

}
```

Somewhere in my app

```js
source: string = new Query("&", {
    foo: "bar",
    goo: "car",
    group: new Query("&", {
      firstName: "john",
      lastName: "doe"
    })
}).generate();

decoded: Query = this._queryService.decode(source);

// source = (&(foo=bar)(goo=car)(&(firstName=john)(lastName=doe)))

// decode will produce a map 
/* {
     operator: "&",
     fields: {
        foo: "bar",
        goo: "car",
        group: {
           operator: "&",
           fields: {
               firstName: "john",
               lastName: "doe"
           }
       }
   } */
```

of course I can handle multiple groups at the same level, but for now this is enough. I'll improve the code gradually.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let match = null;
const regex = /(\([^&|]+?=.+?)\)/g;
while (match = regex.exec('(&(foo=bar)(goo=car))')) {
  console.log(match[0]);
}
```

Comment: Excellent it works even with a nested query, like `(&(foo=bar)(goo=car)(|(hoo=dar)(ioo=ear))`. Is there a way to extract the operators as well? (& or |)

Comment: would this be ok? `([&|])|(\([^&|]+?=.+?)\)`

Comment: This could also match content between parenthesis without taking the structure of the data into account https://regex101.com/r/luxTgG/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird this wasn't bad but I need to know the operator. I think the only possible solution was to use multiple regular expressions. I did it.